# Azure SQL : error code for Connection is closed exception's

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, azure-sql-database

I am getting below exceptions at times in my java code which connects to Azure SQL server. For this, I need to implement retry logic i.e. when I face below exception I will retry 1) Create new connection 2) Re-execute the SQL query 3) Commit the transaction.

But, I am unable to get the Azure SQL server error code for below error. Please let me know the error code ? I do not see the error code when I run below query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE language_id = 1033
```

Exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:227)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:796)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.commit(SQLServerConnection.java:2681)
```

Also, is it a good practice to use `e.getMessage()` and check if return string is "The connection is closed." and retry my logic ?

I do not see the error code in [Error codes from SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-develop-error-messages)

Comment: I believe the error state it clear. The SQL connection is closed. Have you tried opening the connection before executing the query??

Comment: Yeah, I know the connection is closed. I need to know the error code of the above exception, so that I can compare the error code and re establish connection

Answer (score 0):

This exception seems to be related to an attempt to convert from a supported data type to an unsupported data type. [This](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/512) is a good example.

Try another version of the JDBC driver.

Comment: Look at possible unsupported data type conversions it is just not only timestamp. Did you read the whole Github thread? They suggest to try with another version of driver.